# NatTable preserve row selection on clear data and reload

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

I use the below snippet to clear the NatTable data and do a complete reload on refresh action.

```
natTable.getBodyDataProvider().getList().clear();
natTable.getBodyDataProvider().getList().addAll(inputList);
natTable.refresh();
```

Since, the data is cleared and reset, I am unable to set the row selection back to previously selected row before refresh.

However, I am using the RowSelectionModel successfully to restore selection on Sort

```
final RowSelectionModel<T> rowSelectionModel = new RowSelectionModel<T>(bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer(),bodyDataProvider, rowIdAccessor);
bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer().setSelectionModel(rowSelectionModel);
```

Is it possible to restore row selection when data is cleared and reloaded??

I did see existing question on PreserveModel : [How to use Nebula NatTable's PreserveSelectionModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212455/how-to-use-nebula-nattables-preserveselectionmodel) But it did not answer my question.

Appreciate if anyone could give more pointers regarding this.

Regards,
SDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC when you clear the underlying list (and I suppose you are using GlazedLists so there is an event fired when you do so), the `RowSelectionModel` clears the internally stored selections. Which is consistent, as it does not make sense to keep a selection for an object that has been removed.

So you need to implement a workaround that deals with that fact. That can be for example to implement a custom `ISelectionModel` that extends the `RowSelectionModel` and ensures consistency with the underlying list in a different way. Or you remember the selection before you clear the underlying list, and apply the selection afterwards again. But to do this you need to register a `PaintListener` on NatTable to apply the selection late, otherwise the internal events will clear the selection with a delay.

The following snippet for example will always select the 5th row in the body region of a NatTable, which is the 6th row in the NatTable because of the column header row.

```
natTable.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        // use column 1 as column 0 in NatTable is the row header
        // insert the rows to select that you previously cached
        natTable.doCommand(
                new SelectRowsCommand(natTable, 1, 5, false, false));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply Dirk. I am caching the selection Object and on clear and reload I set the selection back using rowSelectionProviderNatTable.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(previousSelectedObj)); This doesnot set the selection back to the Table. Since, NatTable is already having the Paintlistener, is there a DefaultPaintListner that I can use?

Comment: Don't understand the question. Why can't you add another PaintListener?

Comment: I am new to NatTable and SWT PaintListener. Appreciate if you could share code snippet for setting row selection. Thank you.

Comment: Works well! Thank you very much for the answer. I am fetching the rowPosition using int rowIndex = ((IRowDataProvider)bodyDataProvider).indexOfRowObject(selectedObj);
                    int rowPosition = selectionLayer.getRowPositionByIndex(rowIndex);  natTable.doCommand(
                new SelectRowsCommand(natTable, 1, rowPosition, false, false));