# How to restore selection in nattable after nattable refresh?

Tags: eclipse, nattable

Using
-nattable.doCommand(new StructuralRefreshCommand())
-nattable.refresh()

Now I want to retain selection in the nat table

When I use-
natpage.selectionProvider().getSelection();after refresh selection is no longer available

How do I retain selection in natable so that user can update same selected row multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Use `natTable.refresh(false)` as it sounds you do not change the structure of the underlying data model and therefore a structural refresh is not needed.

You can also have a look here to get more information:
[NatTable preserve row selection on clear data and reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46229340/nattable-preserve-row-selection-on-clear-data-and-reload)

Comment: Thank you it works in case underlying data model's structure is not changed.

Comment: But is there a way to retain selection after both

Comment: natTable.doCommand(new StructuralRefreshCommand()) and natTable.doCommand(VisualRefreshCommand()),without using PaintListener

Comment: Also even after using natTable.refresh(false), selection is getting lost on sorting the columns?

Comment: You can try to use the RowSelectionModel or the PreserveSelectionModel. With those models the selection can be restored based on a row ID.